# Add a TextView dynamically in a layout ANDROID

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, textview, addition

I want to create two TextView dynamically and show them in a linearLayout called activity_ranking. I try this and the LogCat says that the problem is in the line: "ranking.addView(fecha);" Do you know what it happens? Thanks!

```
public void listarPuntuaciones(){

    LinearLayout ranking = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.activity_ranking);


       for(int i=0; i<puntuaciones.size(); i++){


       String aux[]=this.puntuaciones.elementAt(i).split(";");

       TextView fecha = new TextView(this);
       Log.i(aux[0],"aux0");
       fecha.setText(aux[0]);
       ranking.addView(fecha);

       TextView puntos = new TextView(this);
       Log.i(aux[1],"aux1");
       puntos.setText(aux[1]);
       ranking.addView(puntos);
       }
}
```

Comment: And which problem exactly shows `LogCat`? Post full stack trace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess `ranking` is null, because when you tried to find it byId, you should have given `R.id.layout_id` as a parameter.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735566/null-pointer-exception-when-referencing-main-layout)